# Rails g controller with irregular plural

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first question and my english is not very good, so I am sorry if you don't understand very well.

I want to create a Asset Life table in my database and a controller. To the model I'll use:

`rails g model AssetLife [fields]`

But I don't know the command how to generate the controller for the same, since I know that the plural of life is lives. Rails recognize the difference?

Comment: Rails already has an inflection for life set up. `"life".pluralize == "lives"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails already has an inflection for life set up. `"life".pluralize == "lives"`. You can just use `String#pluralize|#singularize` in the console to test if an inflection exists:

```
irb(main):001:0> "wife".pluralize
=> "wives"
irb(main):002:0> "information".pluralize
=> "information"
irb(main):003:0> "money".pluralize
=> "money"
```

Looking good so far. But oh noes:

```
irb(main):004:0> "feet".pluralize
=> "feets"
irb(main):005:0> "goose".pluralize
=> "gooses"
```

Inflections are usually setup in `/config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'goose', 'geese'
  inflect.uncountable %w( feet )
end
```

You can also just run the generator and use `rails destroy` which is the the inverse of `rails generate` if the results are not what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rails knows that in most cases. Rails use `ActiveSupport::Inflector` to know the plural of words. If it is not in the list known by Rails, you can configure it via `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.

Good to know, you can also use `rails g scaffold` to create model, migration and controller. It handle pluralization.